# How to insert <raj> at starting and </raj> at the end of the text using sed?

Tags: shell, sed

I need to write a shell script which should check whether a text file contains `<raj>` and `</raj>`. If the text file contains `<raj>` then we need to add `</raj>` alone and vice versa; if it contains neither, add both.

My text file contains following content.

```
1123
1111
2222
3333
```

I want the output below.

```
<raj>
1123
1111
2222
3333
</raj>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the below Perl command.

```
perl -0777pe 's/^<raj>\n|\n<\/raj>$//s;s/(.*)/<raj>\n\1<\/raj>\n/s' file
```

If you don't care about slurping the whole file into memory at once, then you could use the above perl one-liner command.

Answer (score 2):

This does the job:

```
sed -e '1{/^<raj>/!i\
<raj>
}
${/^<\/raj>/!a\
</raj>
}' data.4
```

On the first line, if the line does not match `<raj>`, insert `<raj>` before the current line.
On the last line, if the line does not match `</raj>`, append `</raj>` after the current line.

For each of the four input files below, the script above produces the output matching the last input (`data.4`).

#### data.1

```
1123
1111
2222
3333
```

#### data.2

```
<raj>
1123
1111
2222
3333
```

#### data.3

```
1123
1111
2222
3333
</raj>
```

#### data.4

```
<raj>
1123
1111
2222
3333
</raj>
```

---

#### Removing stray tags

If the output is supposed to have the `<raj>` tag at the top and the `</raj>` at the bottom, and any intervening tags should be deleted, then this modified script will do the job.  It is actually simpler.  It outputs `<raj>` before line 1; it outputs `</raj>` after the last line; it deletes any line starting `<raj>` or `</raj>`.

```
sed -e '1i\
<raj>
$a\
</raj>
/^<raj>/d
/^<\/raj>/d'
```

It produces the same output as before on `data.1`…`data.4`.

#### data.5

== data.5 ==

```
1123
1111
2222
3333
<raj>
1123
1111
2222
3333
</raj>
1123
1111
2222
3333
</raj>
```

Given `data.5`, the output is:

```
<raj>
1123
1111
2222
3333
1123
1111
2222
3333
1123
1111
2222
3333
</raj>
```

If that isn't what you're after, then you need to specify what you want more carefully.

Comment: never say that <raj> is in the first line, so you need to test for all file before adding or not the tag

Comment: @NeronLeVelu: 'Tis easily done if that's the requirement; for example, add `/^<raj>/d` on the line between the first `}` and the line starting `$`.

Comment: but in this case you add it at first line but he specify to let it at the same place in this case

Comment: The question does not specify exactly what is required in such circumstances.  It barely explains what is wanted when neither is present.  You may add an alternative answer that meets your interpretation of the requirements — and I have doubts that it can be done in `sed` sensibly for what you're defining.

Comment: Agree with your point of view and this is certainly the meaning reading between the lines of the request

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n 'H;${x
 /\n<raj>/ !s/./&<raj>&/
 \#\n</raj># !s#\(.\).*#&</raj>\1#
 s/.//p
 }' YourFile
```

Load the whole file in buffer, than check presence of tag and add it if missing. 1 check per tag. finally print the result

Comment: For plausible sizes of files (say, less than 1 GiB), this will work fine on most modern machines.  For truly monstrous files, slurping may end up failing.  When I run it on my `data.1` file, the last but one line of output is `3333</raj>` and there is a blank line after it; ditto for `data.2`.  And `data.5` is left with two occurrences of `</raj>` in it.

Comment: The `</raj>` problem (for `data.1` and `data.2`) can be fixed using `\#\n</raj># !s#\(.\).*$#&\1</raj>#` in place of what you have.  It isn't clear what the requirement is if either tag appears several times in the input — what you've got is a legitimate interpretation.

Comment: for monsturous file, maybe a batch that first grep the presence of tag  so we can handle just the add if needed or take your approach that use a line by line and put tag at the start/end of file